# rxjs5 takeUntil does now allow passing of a Subject... TypeScript error

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

So all of a sudden (well after running npm update) I am getting this new error:

```
Error:(109, 30) TS2345:Argument of type 'Subject<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<any>'.
  Property 'source' is protected but type 'Observable<T>' is not a class derived from 'Observable<T>'.
```

On this code:

```
private totalPlayersSubject$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
...

items$.takeUntil(this.totalPlayersSubject$).subscribe((x) => {
                    this.m_stations = List<any>(x);
                    this.cd.markForCheck();
                }
            )
```

Any ideas as to why? As I am passing a Subject to takeUntil, which is valid AFAIK...

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: Is this really the line causing the error?

Comment: `but type 'Observable<T>' is not a class derived from 'Observable<T>'` --> this might be some multiple instances of the typings or some cached source-files maybe? - could that be?

Comment: this works ```private totalPlayersSubject$: any = new Subject();``` but that's no fun :(

Comment: then this should work as well: `items$.takeUntil<any>(this.totalPlayersSubject$)...` - with your original typing of course

Comment: @born2net Are you sure you don't reassign `totalPlayersSubject$` somewhere? Btw, how is `items$` defined?

Comment: I don't ... tx for the replies, see here: https://github.com/born2net/studioDashboard/blob/master/src/comps/app1/dashboard/StationsGrid.ts

Comment: I did this as an ugly working ```items$.takeUntil((this.totalPlayersSubject$ as any))```

Comment: `.takeUntil<any>(..)` did not work? that would leave the subject intact and just cast the contained value of the subject

Comment: it did not, I know it's odd, but ```as any``` worked...

Comment: @born2net, How are you importing rxjs types? What exact version of rxjs and angular are you using?

Comment: you can see the file here https://github.com/born2net/studioDashboard/blob/master/src/comps/app1/dashboard/StationsGrid.ts I am using rxjs 5.0.2 and latest 2.4 ng2 and importing via ```import {Subject, Observable} from "rxjs";``` ragards

Comment: @born2net, Try to use the same version of rxjs in your ng-mslib package

Comment: I looked and both are using 5.0.2